# Load html in vue.js component attribute

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am not entirely sure how I should name this question and that might be the reason why I cannot find any information about this online, so please correct me if I am wrong.

I am using the steps component from [Element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/steps)

```
<el-steps :active="active" align-center>
  <el-step v-for="(el,idx) in certain_list" :key="idx" :title="getTitle(el)">
  </el-step>
</el-steps>
```

Now I would like to not set text as the title attribute, but for instance an editable input field. I hoped this was possible by returning html in the getTitle function, but I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do this as I also want to use v-model on this input field.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You can do it, but if your trying to return an html input as the value its not going to render correctly since the attribute is expecting a `string`. But perhaps you can place an input inside the `el-step` element? Like `<el-step><input v-model="" /></el-step>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      active: 0,
      certain_list: [
        {title: 'Title1'},
        {title: 'Title2'},
        {title: 'Title3'}
      ]
    };
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <el-steps :active="active" align-center>
    <el-step v-for="(el,idx) in certain_list" :key="idx">
      <el-input slot="title" v-model="el.title"></el-input>
    </el-step>
  </el-steps>
</div>
```

Override the `title` attribute by using a named `slot`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!